# Boost build fails to generate visual studio manifest file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I'm attempting to build Boost from source and running into an odd issue.  Some Windows machines can compile this just fine and others fail even though they're all running the same version of Visual Studio. This worked on all machines using Boost 1.62 but is failing with Boost 1.72.

Here's the Boost build command:

```
b2 -j${num_processors} -d 0 --layout=versioned architecture=x86 address-model=64 threading=multi
link=shared runtime-link=shared toolset=msvc-14.0 --with-system --with-thread --with-date_time
--with-chrono --with-filesystem --with-atomic variant=debug --prefix=${boost_dir} install
```

The issue seems to be that Boost Thread isn't getting configured properly such that the project's .MANIFEST file is not generated.  Here's the error output (see last line):

```
>  bin.v2\libs\headers\build\install\boost_headers-config.cmake
>          1 file(s) copied.
>  msvc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threadapi-win32\threading-multi\boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_72.dll
>
>          call "bin.v2\standalone\msvc\msvc-14.0\address-model-64\architecture-x86\msvc-setup.bat" amd64 >nul
>   link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console /out:"bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threadapi-win32\threading-multi\boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_72.dll"
       /IMPLIB:"bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threadapi-win32\threading-multi\boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib"
       @"bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threadapi-win32\threading-multi\boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_72.dll.rsp"
>          if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%
>
>     Creating library bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threadapi-win32\threading-multi\boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib
         and object bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threadapi-win32\threading-multi\boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_72.exp
>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\threadapi-win32\threading-multi\boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_72.dll.manifest'
```

Any ideas what would trigger this or suggestions on what I can investigate further?

EDIT: We're building this on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: There are already built [boost binaries for Visual Studio](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.72.0/).  Maybe by using the prebuilt binaries, the issue may get resolved.

Comment: Prebuilt binaries are not an option in my environment.

Comment: You should mention the environment you're building for.  Or at least explain why the prebuilt binaries are not an option.

Comment: Various industries have legal requirements that all software run on air-gapped networks and all incoming software be built from source.  Therefore prebuilt binaries are not an option in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, the team upgraded to Visual Studio 2019.  This at least worked around the issue for most of us.  A few folks still have issues.